# How can I use and compare string datetime in c# linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have database on my PC,and into that DB date save in `nchar` format,i want use this query:

```
 var query = (from t in behzad.STATUS
              where DateTime.Parse(t.date) >= DateTime.Parse("1394/4/21") <= DateTime.Parse(NOW)
              select p).ToArray();
```

but I get this error:

> Additional information: Method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)'
>   has no supported translation to SQL.

How can i solve that problem?

Comment: Change the database to use proper dates instead of strings.

Comment: @DavidG i can't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ToList() to come out of SQL domain, and try to parse the date then, something like this:

```
var query = (from t in behzad.STATUS.ToList()
              where DateTime.Parse(t.date) >= new DateTime(1394,4,21) <= DateTime.Now
              select p).ToArray();
```

**EDIT:** Note that this `ToList()` would fetch all the data from `behzad.STATUS` entity, and could cause overhead for large result sets.

Comment: It might be but sometimes you can only work with what you've been given

Comment: @DavidG He's just asking about parsing of database string, which is known not to work with DateTime.Parse(). The answer reflects only that.

Comment: @user3671271 Be warned that if/when this table grows, your application will now grind to a halt because of this.

Comment: @DavidG I've already added a note in the original answer to warn him :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the parse method in linq to entities and you are using a string value in the db object so cannot parse before and pass in a variable. Try getting your results and then filtering them. This is not ideal with large data sets as you pull a lot more data into memory but is the easiest way to do it:

```
var data = behzad.STATUS.ToList();
var query = data.Where(t => DateTime.Parse(t.date) >= DateTime.Parse("1394/4/21") <= DateTime.Parse(NOW)).ToArray();
```

To do it without pulling back all data first your probably best changing the database to store dates instead of string sthen you could do this:

```
var date1 = DateTime.Parse("1394/4/21");
var date2 = DateTime.Parse(NOW); //If this is the time now then try using DateTime.Now or DateTime.Today
var query = behzad.STATUS.Where(t => t.date/*this is now a dateTime object*/ >= date1 <= date2).ToArray();
```